# EF5 Code First Cascade on delete

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is there any way to Get a cascade on delete to happen when I remove a computer? Basically when I delete a computer I want it to remove the instance and all its references except Environments and Product.

Computer Entity:

```
public class Computer
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string IpAddress { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string UserFriendlyName { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Instance Entity:

```
    public class Instance
{
    public Instance()
    {
        TestResults = new HashSet<TestResult>();
        Environments = new HashSet<Environment>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Version { get; set; }

    public string UserFriendlyName { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

    public virtual Profile LastKnownProfile { get; set; }

    public virtual Computer Computer { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TestResult> TestResults { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Environment> Environments { get; set; } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the relationships using the Fluent API. Use something like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder.Entity<Computer>()
                .HasRequired(x => x.Instance)
                .WithRequiredPrincipal(x => x.Computer)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete();

  modelBuilder.Entity<Instance>()
                .HasRequired(x => x.LastKnownProfile)
                .WithRequiredPrincipal(x => x.Instance)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete();

  modelBuilder.Entity<Instance>()
                .HasMany(x => x.TestResults)
                .WithOptional(x => x.Instance)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete();
}
```

This is documented pretty well on MSDN: [Configuring Relationships with the Fluent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620)

Answer (score 0):

check many to many relationship.is turning off cascade delete for State and deleting the related records manually

Comment: Yes, it is turned off. However I'm more concerned with how to configure it to delete the instance when a computer gets deleted.