# Deleting object with child entries from database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm very new to Model First and Entity Framework 4.1, and always created my small databases without relations, and implying those by putting reference fields in the child tables. I tried to give Model First a try and created a database with 3 tables with one to many relationships between each other, so:
Grandfather -> Father -> Son

When i try to delete with the following code it doesn't work:

> DBUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

Code:

```
var toDelete = db.Grandfathers.Find(id);
db.GrandFathers.Remove(toDelete);
db.SaveChanges();
```

But when i delete them recursively with the following code everything goes well as expected.

```
db.Grandfathers.Where(g=>g.Id = id).SelectMany(f=>f.Fathers).SelectMany(s=>s.Sons).ToList().ForEach(r => db.Sons.Remove(r));
db.SaveChanges();

db.Grandfathers.Where(g=>g.Id = id).SelectMany(f=>f.Fathers).ToList().ForEach(r => db.Fathers.Remove(r));
db.SaveChanges();

db.Grandfathers.Where(g=>g.Id = id).ToList().ForEach(r => db.Grandfathers.Remove(r));
db.SaveChanges();
```

How can i delete all the child records from the Grandfather record without going through all of this?

Comment: What is the inner exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either set cascade delete when defining the database schema (in your database if you are using Database First or see [EF5 Code First Cascade on delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14774444/ef5-code-first-cascade-on-delete) if you are using Code First) or delete manually as you did (by the way you don't need to call SaveChanges() each time).